# add or subtract from a DateTime in Swing Java

Tags: java, swing, jodatime

I want to add/subtract a number of years, months, or days to or from a DateTime. Im using Jodatime for dates and this is my code :

```
else if (e.getSource()==calcul1){
            Date date1 = (Date) datePicker3.getDate();
            DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);

            if ( ajout.isSelected()){

            dt1.plusYears((Integer)anlist.getValue());
            dt1.plusMonths((Integer)moilist.getValue());
            dt1.plusDays((Integer)jourlist.getValue());
            }
            if (soustr.isSelected()){
                dt1.minusYears((Integer)anlist.getValue());
                dt1.minusMonths((Integer)moilist.getValue());
                dt1.minusDays((Integer)jourlist.getValue());
            }
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy");
            textdate.setText(formatter.print(dt1));
        }
```

The problem is that I always get the date of today in the JTextField, what shows that my datetime is not changing despite the operations of adding and subtracting.

Comment: Try using java.util.Calendar

Comment: Are you sure that at least one (but not both) of `ajout` and `soustr` is selected?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight yes. `Ajout` and `soustr` are two JRadioButtons and i have set one of them checked by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The addition and subtraction methods return a new DateTime. Try this:

```
else if (e.getSource()==calcul1){
        Date date1 = (Date) datePicker3.getDate();
        DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(date1);

        if ( ajout.isSelected()){

        dt1 = dt1.plusYears((Integer)anlist.getValue());
        dt1 = dt1.plusMonths((Integer)moilist.getValue());
        dt1 = dt1.plusDays((Integer)jourlist.getValue());
        }
        if (soustr.isSelected()){
            dt1 = dt1.minusYears((Integer)anlist.getValue());
            dt1 = dt1.minusMonths((Integer)moilist.getValue());
            dt1 = dt1.minusDays((Integer)jourlist.getValue());
        }
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEEE dd MMMM yyyy");
        textdate.setText(formatter.print(dt1));
    }
```

Comment: You're very welcome. I make that mistake all the time wondering why my Object wont change via whatever method.

Comment: @Souad would you mark the question as answered if this solution works for you?

Comment: Correct answer. Joda-Time (and java.time) uses [immutable objects](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object). Rather than alter the values in an objects's member variables ("mutate" the object), a new object is created with values based on the original while using alternative values in particular member variables. The purpose is to promote [thread-safety](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). The call to `plusYears` Instantiates a new DateTime object, redirects the `dt1` reference variable (pointer) to that new instance, while surrendering the old object to garbage-collection.